# WPF/XAML code generators

Tags: c#, wpf, code-generation

Do you use a code generator for WPF/XAML?
If so, in what capacity?
Is it 3rd party/in-house?

Comment: I think almost everybody does.  The designer in Visual Studio is a code generator.  What other kind do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know that [XAML power toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/) got some code generation but i don't know what it does.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the xaml export in InkScape before, which outputs vector graphics in xaml format:
http://www.inkscape.org/

Answer (score 1):

Auto Generation of WPF Forms from SQL Server databases

Original description:
http://blogs.solidq.com/EN/kspencer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=7143871b-e32e-4906-ae07-18f11d62b3fb&ID=2

2nd gen version:
http://blogs.solidq.com/EN/kspencer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=7143871b-e32e-4906-ae07-18f11d62b3fb&ID=60

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code generator to create a WPF UI to reflect a database, but it doesn't generate any XAML, it does it all in C#. It didn't take very long, and I'm very happy with it. Here's a [screenshot](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/9449/gridt.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

theres a good one at www.codetrigger.com that does WPF sample generation with c# code generation & domain/class models and sql stored procedures